# Finding intersection point of curves $y=\cos x$ and $y = \frac{3x}{2\pi}$ with $x \geq 0$

Tags: calculus, area, curves

I just need to find the intersection point of those two curves greater than zero on the $x$-axis. I really only need $x$ now that I think about it. I will use this information to find the area enclosed by the curves.

I completely forget how to go about this, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They intersect at
$$x=\pi/3$$
because
$$\cos (\pi/3)=1/2$$

To prove uniqueness, define
$$f(x)=\frac{3}{2\pi}x-\cos x$$
and notice that
$$f'(x)=\frac{3}{2\pi}+\sin x$$

Now for $0\le x \le \pi$, $\sin x \ge 0$, and so $f'(x)>0$.

For $x>\pi$, $f(x)>0$ because $|\cos x| \le 1$.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not seeing the connection. Could you expand on it? I'm completely lost as to how you got that. I'm sure I knew once, but its just not coming to me. Is there a way to do it algebraically? Or only by inspection?

Comment: Sorry, I got it by inspection, not derivation.